# How do I can remove the label above input file form?

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

I've an application that was developed using Yii2, and this application I've use *Kartik Input File* for upload file.

#### Case

[image]
From the example above, I want to remove / hide the "File" label.

And I think, that label based on `model` name.

This is the code I use:

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'file')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'accept' => 'doc/*', 'file/*',
        'enableLabel' => false,
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowedFileExtensions' => ['csv', 'xls', 'xlsx'],
        'showUpload' => FALSE,
        'showPreview' => FALSE,
    ]
]);
?>
```

How do I can remove the label above?

Thanks

Comment: Try hiding it using plain css

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar Yah, you're right. I just need to hide di element using css. Thanks :)

Comment: ->label(false); add this at end of your ]) last bracket

Answer (score 3):

For removing the label you can simply use the following:

```
<?=
$form->field($model, 'file')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => [
        'accept' => 'doc/*', 'file/*',
        'enableLabel' => false,
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowedFileExtensions' => ['csv', 'xls', 'xlsx'],
        'showUpload' => FALSE,
        'showPreview' => FALSE,
    ]
])->label(false);
?>
```